# How to say "you have good taste"?

Tags: phrase-requests

If you want to tell someone that he *has good taste* in music/poetry/etc, what is the best way to do it? I have some ideas, but there are probably better ways to say it than  "*vi elektas bone tion kion vi ŝatas*" and "*vi ŝatas kio bonas*".

Answer (score 2):

"... **havas bonan guston**"

Jen la tria difino de **gusto** el PIV/vortaro.net

- Sagaca k ĝusta senco pri la kvalitoj k mankoj de arta verko: pentraĵoj, kiujn povis elekti nur homo kun gusto<sup>Z</sup>; por tio (juvelarto) oni bezonas **bonan guston**<sup>Z</sup>; ŝi vestas sin kun gusto; tio estas eraro de gusto; oni povas distingi la guston naturan k la guston akiritan; aĉgusta ĉapelo; rimarko de duba gusto.